# Why does this render differently between Chrome & Firefox 3.6?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

http://jsbin.com/ohuwu4/5

(The example is taken from [Google's CSS walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mgyfwYKpmQ&feature=player_embedded))

BTW, I tried to make this pass validation, but I couldn't get jsbin to put a type attribute on the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's this [collapsing margin bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791).

Changing the CSS to:

```
#wd-c div { margin: 0 1em 1em; }
```

seems to fix it (and for me confirms it's the `margin-top` CSS as mentioned in the bug report). However, you lose the margin on all the `<div>`s which isn't desired.

To fix that, I then added:

```
#wd-1 { margin-top:1em !important; }
```

to put it back on the first one and it renders the same in both browsers.